# If for each neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ there exists $x\in U$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)$, then $f'(x_0)=0$ or $f'(x_0)$ does not exist.

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

Prove the following:

If for each neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$ there exists $x\in U$ such that $f(x)=f(x_0)$ with $x\neq x_0$, then $f'(x_0)=0$ or $f'(x_0)$ does not exist.

I am not sure how to start this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you assume the function is continuous, then you can apply Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: This would tell me that there exists $c\in(x,x_0)$ (or $(x_0,x)$) such that $f'(c)=0$. How can I deduce that $c=x_0$?

Comment: You can reapply Rolle's theorem to arbitrarily small intervals around $x_0$, and take their intersection, which is $x_0$, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If $f'(x_{0})$ does not exist, then we are done.

Assume that $f'(x_{0})$ exists, then consider the ball $B_{1/n}(x_{0})$, then by assumption we have some $x_{n}\in B_{1/n}(x_{0})$ such that $x_{n}\ne x_{0}$ and $f(x_{n})=f(x_{0})$. Given $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that 
\begin{align*}
\left|\dfrac{f(x_{0}+h)-f(x_{0})}{h}-f'(x_{0})\right|<\epsilon,~~~~0<|h|<\delta.
\end{align*}
Find $n_{0}$ so large such that $0<|x_{n_{0}}-x_{0}|<\delta$, then
\begin{align*}
|f'(x_{0})|=\left|\dfrac{f(x_{n_{0}})-f(x_{0})}{x_{n_{0}}-x_{0}}-f'(x_{0})\right|<\epsilon,
\end{align*}
since this is true for all $\epsilon>0$, we have $f'(x_{0})=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the definition of a ball.

Comment: Just interval $(x_{0}-1/n,x_{0}+1/n)$.